# mysql: comparing two columns

Tags: mysql, regex, select, join

my tables and their layout:

```
mysql> select * FROM xt_shipping_zones;
+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| zone_id | zone_name   | zone_countries                                                            |
+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       5 | ZONE1       | AT,BE,BG,DK,FI,FR,GR,IE,IT,LV,LT,LU,MC,NL,PL,PT,RO,SM,SE,SK,SI,ES,HU,GB   |
|       6 | Deutschland | DE                                                                        |
|       8 | ZONE2Brutto | AD,NO,VA                                                                  |
|       9 | ZONE2NETTO  | CH,LI                                                                     |
+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


mysql> select * FROM xt_shipping_cost WHERE shipping_geo_zone = 99995 LIMIT 5;
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| shipping_cost_id | shipping_id | shipping_geo_zone | shipping_country_code | shipping_type_value_from | shipping_type_value_to | shipping_price | shipping_allowed |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------------+------------------+
|              269 |          34 |             99995 |                       |                     0.31 |                  17.99 |        17.0000 |                1 |
|              270 |          34 |             99995 |                       |                    17.99 |                  35.99 |        34.0000 |                1 |
|              271 |          34 |             99995 |                       |                    35.99 |                  53.99 |        51.0000 |                1 |
|              272 |          34 |             99995 |                       |                    53.99 |                  71.99 |        68.0000 |                1 |
|              273 |          34 |             99995 |                       |                    71.99 |                  89.99 |        85.0000 |                1 |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+----------------+------------------+


mysql> SELECT * FROM geoip WHERE 92569600 BETWEEN start AND end;
+----------+----------+---------+-----+
| start    | end      | country | id  |
+----------+----------+---------+-----+
| 92569600 | 92585983 | AT      | 895 |
+----------+----------+---------+-----+
```

My Query:

```
SELECT
  xt_shipping_cost.shipping_type_value_from,
  xt_shipping_cost.shipping_type_value_to,
  xt_shipping_cost.shipping_price,
  geoip.country
FROM xt_shipping_cost
  INNER JOIN xt_shipping_zones
    ON xt_shipping_cost.shipping_geo_zone = xt_shipping_zones.zone_id + 99990
  INNER JOIN geoip
    ON geoip.country REGEXP xt_shipping_zones.zone_countries
WHERE 34664448 BETWEEN geoip.start AND geoip.end
```

My Problem:

Query is working if there is only *ONE* entry in *xt_shipping_zones.zone_countries* like DE. If there are multiple (with comma seperated entries) i cant get a match on that row.

Doing it manually:

```
mysql> SELECT *  FROM  `xt_shipping_zones`  WHERE  `zone_countries`  REGEXP  'AT';
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| zone_id | zone_name | zone_countries                                                            |
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       5 | ZONE1     | AT,BE,BG,DK,FI,FR,GR,IE,IT,LV,LT,LU,MC,NL,PL,PT,RO,SM,SE,SK,SI,ES,HU,GB   |
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68f8d0/1

I hope i didn't failed to much to make my problem clear.

Thank you

Comment: It is no good idea to store the values as csv. That is very bad database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `find_in_set()`

```
SELECT
  xt_shipping_cost.shipping_type_value_from,
  xt_shipping_cost.shipping_type_value_to,
  xt_shipping_cost.shipping_price,
  geoip.country
FROM xt_shipping_cost
  INNER JOIN xt_shipping_zones
    ON xt_shipping_cost.shipping_geo_zone = xt_shipping_zones.zone_id + 99990
  INNER JOIN geoip
    ON find_in_set(geoip.country, xt_shipping_zones.zone_countries)
WHERE 34664448 BETWEEN geoip.start AND geoip.end
```

It is no good idea to store the values as csv. That is very bad database design.

Comment: of course you are right. anyway, cant change this at the moment. thanks for you reply, but there is still no match.

Comment: @stevo If i change the fiddle to which i mentioned in my answer i get a result of 20 rows.

Comment: ! Thank you very much! Was a mistake on my side! Really Thank you!